# Python Boto3 - how to drop a 'folder' and rename another one?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have these paths in S3:

```
s3://mykey/mytest/file1.txt
s3://mykey/mytest/file2.txt
s3://mykey/mytest/file3.txt
```

and

```
s3://mykey/mytest_temp/file4.txt
s3://mykey/mytest_temp/file5.txt
s3://mykey/mytest_temp/file6.txt
```

Want to drop `s3://mykey/mytest/` (and all files in it) 
and THEN rename `s3://mykey/mytest_temp/` to `s3://mykey/mytest/` while keeping all files in there (`file4, file5, file6`).

Final result should be - only 1 `folder`:

```
s3://mykey/mytest/file4.txt
s3://mykey/mytest/file5.txt
s3://mykey/mytest/file6.txt
```

How to achieve this using `Python Boto3`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS API only allows an operation on one object at a time. Also, there is no "move" command, so you would need to do a Copy and a Delete.

The easiest way to do what you ask is to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) because it has some higher-level commands that can do this easily:

```sh
aws rm --recursive s3://mykey/mytest/
aws mv s3://mykey/mytest_temp/ s3://mykey/mytest/
```

If you didn't want to use the AWS CLI, you could code this operation using boto but you would need to loop through each object and process it individually.

Comment: I do not have access to AWS cli.. Looking for Boto 3 solution..

Comment: In that case, please see my last paragraph. (By the way, what do you mean by "do not have access to"? Are you not permitted to download and install it?)

Comment: I do not have direct access from my machine to AWS using AWS CLI. I also do not have access to create EC2. Only have access to connect to EMR and from there run Python. Therefore asking for Boto 3 solution (not AWS CLI)..

Comment: FYI, it would be useful to put such facts into your Question, so that people seeking similar information in future would be able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

To do this purely from Python using boto3, you would need to do the following:

**Deleting existing 'folder'**

- Call [`list_objects_v2()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2), passing in a Prefix to obtain a listing of the directory
- Take the results and pass the object names into a [`delete_objects()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.delete_objects) call

Please note that each of these API calls handle up to 1000 objects each. If you have more than 1000 objects, you would need to paginate the results by calling them again.

**'Renaming' objects**

Amazon S3 does not have a 'rename' command. Instead, it will be necessary to **copy** each object to a new key, then **delete** the original object.

- Call [`list_objects_v2()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2), passing in a Prefix to obtain a listing of the directory
- Loop through each object and:

  - Call [`copy_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy_object), specifying a **full path** in the destination Key
  - Call [`delete_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.delete_object) after the object has been copied

Answer (score 0):

I have a Django project where I needed the ability to rename a folder but still keep the directory structure in-tact, meaning empty folders would need to be copied and stored in the renamed directory as well.

`aws cli` is great but neither `cp` or `sync` or `mv` copied empty folders (i.e. files ending in '/') over to the new folder location, so I used a mixture of `boto3` and the `aws cli` to accomplish the task.

More or less I find all folders in the renamed directory and then use boto3 to put them in the new location, then I `cp` the data with `aws cli` and finally remove it.

```
import threading

import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse

def rename_folder(request, client_url):
    """
    :param request:
    :param client_url:
    :return:
    """
    current_property = request.session.get('property')
    if request.POST:
        # name the change
        new_name = request.POST['name']
        # old full path with www.[].com?
        old_path = request.POST['old_path']
        # remove the query string
        old_path = ''.join(old_path.split('?')[0])
        # remove the .com prefix item so we have the path in the storage
        old_path = ''.join(old_path.split('.com/')[-1])
        # remove empty values, this will happen at end due to these being folders
        old_path_list = [x for x in old_path.split('/') if x != '']

        # remove the last folder element with split()
        base_path = '/'.join(old_path_list[:-1])
        # # now build the new path
        new_path = base_path + f'/{new_name}/'
        # remove empty variables
        # print(old_path_list[:-1], old_path.split('/'), old_path, base_path, new_path)
        endpoint = settings.AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL
        # # recursively add the files
        copy_command = f"aws s3 --endpoint={endpoint} cp s3://{old_path} s3://{new_path} --recursive"
        remove_command = f"aws s3 --endpoint={endpoint} rm s3://{old_path} --recursive"
        
        # get_creds() is nothing special it simply returns the elements needed via boto3
        client, resource, bucket, resource_bucket = get_creds()
        path_viewing = f'{"/".join(old_path.split("/")[1:])}'
        directory_content = default_storage.listdir(path_viewing)

        # loop over folders and add them by default, aws cli does not copy empty ones
        # so this is used to accommodate
        folders, files = directory_content
        for folder in folders:
            new_key = new_path+folder+'/'
            # we must remove bucket name for this to work
            new_key = new_key.split(f"{bucket}/")[-1]
            # push this to new thread
            threading.Thread(target=put_object, args=(client, bucket, new_key,)).start()
            print(f'{new_key} added')

        # # run command, which will copy all data
        os.system(copy_command)
        print('Copy Done...')
        os.system(remove_command)
        print('Remove Done...')

        # print(bucket)
        print(f'Folder renamed.')
        messages.success(request, f'Folder Renamed to: {new_name}')

    return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', f"{reverse('home', args=[client_url])}"))
```